# After update to Android Studio 3.1 the project does not build: Program type already present: com.sun.activation.registries.LineTokenizer

Tags: android, android-studio, jakarta-mail

I just updated my Android Studio to version 3.1 and I was surprised with an unknown error message: Program type already present: com.sun.activation.registries.LineTokenizer

```
> :testeapn:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug AGPBI:
> {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: com.sun.activation.registries.LineTokenizer","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
> :testeapn:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
> 
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> 
> * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':testeapn:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

After digging a lot I realized the problems was the **javax.mail** library. So, after remove every .jar and every mentions to that library and I could build again, but I removed this feature of my app.

Now I have to make my app to send mails again, but I can't find how to do this and I'm asking you for a help.

I google a lot and found in https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android new information (for me, at least): we should not add the **additionnal.jar**, **mail.jar** and **activation.jar** anymore. We must add new dependencies:

> ```
> implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.1'
> implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.1'
> ```

But, after add those lines in my **app.gradle** and without write a line of code, I got the above error again.

Do someone know what this message means and what to do?

Comment: There's a bug in the Android versions of the 1.6.1 release, try 1.6.0 instead.

Comment: Unbelivable. Thank you very much. After three days the app is working again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem as you after upgrading from the 3 jars (`additionnal.jar`, `mail.jar` and `activation.jar`) to `com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.1` and `com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.1`. I am also using Android Studio 3.1.

**My solution** is, instead of using 1.6.1, using the a little bit older version 1.6.0. The error is gone and the app builds and works again.

> `implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.0'
>   implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.0'`

---

**Some details**

I did a little digging there. It seems the problem is that `com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.1` has a dependency on `javax.activation:activation:1.1`, and both these packages contain `com.sun.activation.registries.*` classes. It caused the build to fail.

On the contrary, the dependency wasn't there in `com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.0`.

The dependency graph is generated by running `gradlew :app:dependencies --configuration debugRuntimeClasspath`.

- when using `1.6.0`

  > `debugRuntimeClasspath - Resolved configuration for runtime for variant: debug
  >   +--- com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.1
  >   |    +--- com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.1
  >   |    |    \--- javax.activation:activation:1.1
  >   |    \--- javax.activation:activation:1.1
  >   +--- com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.1 (*)
  >   +---`
- when using `1.6.0`

  > `debugRuntimeClasspath - Resolved configuration for runtime for variant: debug
  >   +--- com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.0
  >   |    \--- com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.0
  >   +--- com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.0`

You can see it in the following screen shot too.

[Android Studio screen shot when using version 1.6.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFtQG.png)

Though I would like to issue a bug report to their developers. Their old Issue Tracker page (https://github.com/javaee/javamail/issues) is closed, and their new project page on Eclipse Foundation (https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.javamail) is extremely slow that I can barely open it.