# How would I call JavaEmail class from my main Activity?

Tags: java, android, class

This is sample code in a separate java class file in my android studio project. (I left only sample credentials in this example but I replaced them with my actual values in my own code)

```
package com.mytest.java;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class JavaEmail {

    Properties emailProperties;
    Session mailSession;
    MimeMessage emailMessage;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws AddressException,
            MessagingException {

        JavaEmail javaEmail = new JavaEmail();

        javaEmail.setMailServerProperties();
        javaEmail.createEmailMessage();
        javaEmail.sendEmail();
    }

    public void setMailServerProperties() {

        String emailPort = "587";//gmail's smtp port

        emailProperties = System.getProperties();
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", emailPort);
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    }

    public void createEmailMessage() throws AddressException,
            MessagingException {
        String[] toEmails = { "joe@javapapers.com" };
        String emailSubject = "Java Email";
        String emailBody = "This is an email sent by JavaMail api.";

        mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(emailProperties, null);
        emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

        for (int i = 0; i < toEmails.length; i++) {
            emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmails[i]));
        }

        emailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);
        emailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");//for a html email
        //emailMessage.setText(emailBody);// for a text email

    }

    public void sendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

        String emailHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String fromUser = "your emailid here";//just the id alone without @gmail.com
        String fromUserEmailPassword = "your email password here";

        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");

        transport.connect(emailHost, fromUser, fromUserEmailPassword);
        transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
        System.out.println("Email sent successfully.");
    }

}
```

What I tried from onCreate:

```
public class BrowseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        JavaEmail myEmailSender = new JavaEmail();
    }
...
}
```

The JavaEmail never gets sent. I added a log in the file too but I don't see it in my logcat since I'm guessing it's not even calling the constructor.  This has to be a simple problem with my understanding of calling classes but I don't get it yet. The main method of JavaEmail accepts args parameter which I don't think I need so if I remove the main args from the JavaEmail class, I change the onCreate call like this

```
JavaEmail.main();
```

which gives an: Unhandled exception: javax.mail.MessagingException error before compiling.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Java is a deep language. Haven't used it in years and was never an expert. Anyhow thanks for this great article, I got what I needed to work. Nothing fancy but it will do as my test learning subject.

Like Michael posted in his comment it has to be done in the background and I was just assigning the variable and that's not enough for a constructor to run.

I didn't have to load any jar files by adding the following code below my existing code in the build.gradle file to reference the API: (I also had to use the 1.6.0 version of the Library since 1.6.1 crashed)

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        //pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' // picks the JavaMail license file
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/mimetypes.default'
        exclude 'META-INF/mailcap.default'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    //Problem with compiling 1.6.1 so using older version
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49575982/after-update-to-android-studio-3-1-the-project-does-not-build-program-type-alre
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.0'
}
```

https://javapapers.com/android/android-email-app-with-gmail-smtp-using-javamail/

Answer (score 0):

i did something same in swing application where i created one class named SendEmail which has a method which will genrate otp and send it.

```
    class SendEmail
    {
     String from = "username";  // GMail user name
     String pass = "password";
     public void sendOTPEmail(String email)
    {
        String otp=OTP.generate();
        String to[] = {email}; // list of recipient email addresses

        String subject = "One Time Password";
        String body = "<html>\n" +
                        "  <body>\n" +
                        "    <div style='font-size:17px; font-family:cambria'>\n" +
                        "    OTP is generated for changing password of JavaLearn System acount associated with this email.<br><br>\n" +
                        "      Your OTP is:<br>\n" +
                        "     <center>\n" +
                        "      <div style='color:red;font-size:18px; font-family:cambria; border:2px solid black'>\n" +
                        "           \n" +otp+
                        "      </div>\n" +
                        "       </center>\n" +
                        "    </div>\n" +
                        "    </body>\n" +
                        "  </html>";

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        try {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

            // To get the array of addresses
            for( int i = 0; i < to.length; i++ ) {
                toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
            }

            for( int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
            }

            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setContent(body, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, from, pass);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();

            }
     }
```

And from another class i just called a method like this:

```
    String to="abc@gmail.com";
    Thread t1=new Thread(()->{new SendEmail().sendOTPEmail(to);});
    t1.start();
```

Comment: Very interesting. I'm going to try that too. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @pritam, I'm getting a lot of errors.  The Thread line is showing that it's missing a semicolon (;)  It cannot resolve getDefaultInstance, It cannot resolve symbol RecipientType. It cannot resolve constructor MimeMessage(session) and there are a bunch of Unhandled exceptions

Comment: Hey @Mickey D, Sorry there was missing semicolon!! I just edited that part! And make sure you are using jar files required for it. I coded this program long ago, but i guess it requires only 2 jar i.e. activation.jar and mail.jar!

Comment: Yep thanks, I'm guessing it's a pretty old technique since that Thread line is now giving the following error: Lambda expressions are not supported at language level '1.7'